# Variable value not being incremented in glutIdleFunc() in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, opengl, glut

I am trying to continuously increment the variable `bulletY` once I click on letter "b" on the keyboard until the maximum y value window size to give a shooting effect . However `bulletY` is only being incremented once.

Here are the initial values of the bool flags and double used:

```
bool shoot = false;
bool isDone = false;
double bulletX = 8000 ;
double bulletY = -1;
double plusX = 0;
double plusY = 0;
```

Below is the method used to handle key inputs

```
void key(unsigned char k, int x, int y)//keyboard function, takes 3 parameters
                                    // k is the key pressed from the keyboard
                                    // x and y are mouse postion when the key was pressed.
{
    if (k == 'b') { //SHOO
        shoot = true;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();//redisplay to update the screen with the changes
}
```

Finally this is the `Anim` function which i created to be passed to the Idle function `glutIdleFunc(Anim)`

```
void Anim(){
if (shoot==true) {
        bulletX = plusX;
        bulletY = plusY;
        isDone = true;
    }

            if (isDone&& bulletY<450) {
                bulletY += 1;
                std::cout << "bullet Y is currently at : " << bulletY << "\n";
            }
            else {
                isDone = false;
                shoot = false;
            }
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
```

Comment: @wdc I have another object which has translationf values `plusX` and `plusY` and I want the bullet to have the same initial translation values when the keyboard button b is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `bulletY` is always resetting to 0 in your `Anim()` function, and then it is incremented by 1, so `bulletY` is 1 all the time.

Remove `bulletY = plusY` (which is 0) and it should increment in every iteration.